# Add formula to range using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to add a formula to the to a range of cells. It should multiply the a neighbor cell by 100. Therfore I tried the following:

```
Range(Cells(row, col + 17), Cells(row + num_positions, col + 17)).Select
Selection.Formula = "=100*" & Cells(row, col + 12)
```

Unfortunately, this is not the right syntax. How to apply such a behavior?

Edit:

```
 For i = 0 To num_n
    v = Cells(row + i, col + 12)
    Cells(row + i, col+ 17).Formula = "=100*" & v
 Next i
```

If I replace `v` with a constant expression, this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FormulaR1C1`. It's much easier. And avoid loops if you can, they are slow.

```
With Range(Cells(row, col + 17), Cells(row + num_positions, col + 17))
   .FormulaR1C1 = "=100*RC[-5]"  '100 times the cell on the same row, 5 cols left
End with
```

Comment: I just wanted to post my solution with `FormulaR1C1` :D